# Implementing chat client following Beej's guide to network programming

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, posix

I'm trying to learn network programming by following [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html). I have compiled [the server in section 7.2](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select), that's using `select()`, and now I'm trying to write a client for that server, so I could open two terminals on my machine and be able to chat.

I have started off with the [client he gives as an example in section 6.2](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#simpleclient), I could see that if I connect to `localhost` the connection is accepted at the server, so I started off from there.

What I did was editing the part right after the connection to the server is accepted (right after `freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure`) and this is the part of code that I have added.

```
while (1) {

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);

    FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &writefds);

    fcntl(STDIN, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    if (select(sockfd+1, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("client: select");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &writefds)) { // got data from socket, write it to console
        numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0);
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds)) { // got data from stdin, write it to socket
        fgets(buf, MAXDATASIZE, STDIN);
        send(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
    }
}
```

While trying to run this code I have noticed that `recv()` never returns. I know this code is far from perfect but this is my very first shot with sockets so I would love to get some guidance regarding to what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv(2)` is a read operation, so `sockfd` should go in `readfds` instead of `writefds`.

(Where's `STDIN` from by the way? On POSIX systems you can use `STDIN_FILENO`.)

You already said this was simple test code (which is likely to work as expected in practice), but just in case you're not aware of it: `recv()` might split the data up arbitrarily. As an extreme example, it could return it one byte at a time.

Comment: I have `#define`d `STDIN`at the beginning of the code for readability. I'm going to try right away what you said.

Comment: @Quaker: Note that I just corrected an error. `readfds` is correct for stdin, of course. :)

Comment: Note also that `fgets()` will block until you type in a complete line on the terminal, so you'll only see data between typing in lines.

Comment: `fgets()` throws a `segmentation fault` for some reason, so I'm gonna re-implement this block and retry in a minute.

Comment: @Quaker: It's because `STDIN` is an integer and not a `FILE*`. (It's 0, which means you're passing a null pointer. :) Use `stdin` instead (small letters). You could also use `read(2)` directly or just hardcode some test string for `send()`.

Comment: I chose `read()`, but yet I get unexpected behavior, this is how the block above looks now: http://pastebin.com/aseTtpPZ, I am now flooded with unfamiliar characters. This is `client.c`: http://pastebin.com/AAPSHWFd and this is `server.c`: http://pastebin.com/yttBw9L3. edit: I have added '\0' at the end of the string that's being read from `STDIN`.

Comment: @Quaker: See the second comment. I made a typo in the original answer. Both `sockfd` and `STDIN` should go in `readfds`. (This might be unrelated to the problem though.)

Comment: so `readfds` gets them both, and `writefds` gets only `STDIN`?

Comment: `writefds` gets nothing, `readfds` gets both. You're waiting for data to read, either from `stdin` or from the server.

Comment: http://imgur.com/I4C5gnn

Could you please tell me, for the completion of my knowledge, what is writefds used for?

Comment: `writefds` would be for waiting for writing to be possible. For example, if one process is writing to another process, and that other process isn't reading the data, then the buffer will eventually fill up, so that writing would block. `writefds` can be used to get a notification when writing would be possible without blocking (e.g., once the other process has read some data).

Comment: Or the `send()` would return an error (which would be wasted effort) if you're doing non-blocking sockets, which is common with `writefds`. It's not hugely important stuff when starting out though. :)

Comment: One last question, it seems like you haven't finished your last sentence in the original answer, " It's allowed to return it one byte at a time for example if it wants to." if it wants to... what?

Comment: @Quaker: If it wants to return it one byte at a time. Maybe it's questionable English (not a native speaker :), but it sounded alright to my ear.

Comment: I rephrased it a bit.